# Enumerate named destinations

Tags: c#, itext7

I am playing with `iText 7` and I have a problem with getting a list of named destinations.

With previous version 5 it was very easy with helper:

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(_file))
{
    var items = SimpleNamedDestination.GetNamedDestination(reader, false).Select(o => o.Key).ToList();
    ...
}
```

In 7 I can't find helper anymore and have to use this monstrosity (adapted code from [official java example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/clone-named-destinations)):

```
using (var reader = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file)))
{
    var catalog = reader.GetCatalog().GetPdfObject();
    var names = catalog.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Names);
    var dests = names.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Dests);
    var name = dests.GetAsArray(PdfName.Names); // problem

    var items = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < name.Size(); i += 2)
        items.Add(name.GetAsString(i).ToString());
    ...
}
```

Moreover, for some PDFs this code fails with `NullReferenceException` due to `null` returned at `GetAsArray` line.

Looking closely at `PdfDictionary` and `PdfArray` types - they have only 1 entry, no enumerator (!), no LINQ support.

My questions:

- (opinion based, but I am curious to hear the answer) Why iText 7 has less functionality than 5? Im I suppose to mix both?
- (request for off-site resource) Is there proper C# iText 7 documentation somewhere? Converting from java and filtering dozens of questions about it on SO is pretty inefficient.
- (a bit of rant) how the hell I am supposed to debug those types? Talking about `PdfDictionary`, it shows 1 entry, probably not yet parsed content of PDF. I want to see why `GetAsArray` fails, but there is no way for me to debug it.
- (actual question) Why above code fails for some pdf containing named destination (e.g. [this one](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDFOpenParameters.pdf), but I have many more locally)?

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know C#, but in Java, one would get the name tree with the `getNameTree()` method. I assume a similar method `GetNameTree()` exists in the C# version of iText 7:

```
Map<String, PdfObject> names =
    pdfDoc.getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.Dests).getNames();
for (Map.Entry<String, PdfObject> name : names.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Name = " + name.getKey());
    System.out.println("Page = " + name.getValue().toString());
}
```

It would be great if you could update my answer with the C# syntax if it turns out that my answer is helpful.

---

C#:

```
using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file)))
{
    var names = pdf.GetCatalog().GetNameTree(PdfName.Dests).GetNames().Select(o => o.Key).ToList();
    ...
}
```